# Cost of the minimal spanning tree

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees

I can create a grid graph with a random weights of edges and compute its minimal spanning tree by:

```
nx = 3; ny = 5;
G = GridGraph[{nx, ny}];
w = RandomInteger[{1, 6}, EdgeCount[G]];
GG = Graph[EdgeList[G], EdgeWeight -> w, VertexLabels -> "Name",
           VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Italic, 10],
           EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", 
           EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.65`], Blue], 
           EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Italic, 10]];
k = FindSpanningTree[GG];
HighlightGraph[GG, k, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
```

Is there a way to compute the cost of the minimal spanning tree without adding the weights manually?

Answer (score 4):

Up to [FindSpanningTree](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSpanningTree.html), the following does the job:

```
size[g_] :=With[{edges = EdgeList[FindSpanningTree[{g, 1}]]},  Total[PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ edges]]
size[GG]
```

> 30

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

With the current [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) prerelease, you can simply use

```
Total@IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight]@IGSpanningTree[GG]
```

`IGSpanningTree` preserves the edge weights in the tree. `IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight]` is an operator that extracts the edge weights into a list.